# How can I use NSFetchedResultsController to fetch results based on an entity's relationship?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have 2 views that contain a UITableView each. They are both displayed at the same time, side  by side, on an iPad.

I am using Core Data for all data. Both tables need to be edited (rows added, deleted, etc), so I'd like to use a NSFetchedResultsController in each view to handle all this for me.

The contents of the second table depend on what is selected in the first table. So, when selecting an item in the first table, that object is passed to the view with the second table (so I do already have access to the data that should go into the second table), but I'd like to try to use all the built-in handling of the NSFRC if possible.

The model is along the lines of: University (uniID, uniName, students) and Student (stuID, stuName, university). So the relationship is: University <-->> Student.

I'm using the following code in the NSFRC, but it's returning 0 results:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"stuName" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"university == %@",self.selectedUniversity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[sort release];
[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

I would be most grateful if someone could at least point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the issue. The NSFRC wasn't being updated when the predicate term needed to change (i.e. a University had been selected), of course, because of:

```
if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Having the NSFRC recreated every time it's called (by removing the above code) doesn't work either, because the fetch needs to be executed after it's been created, which can't happen just before numberOfRowsInSection is called (as this method calls, and therefore recreates, the NSFRC).

So, I added a BOOL to the view called newFetchRequired which is set to YES every time a new University is selected. In the NSFRC, the above code should be changed to:

```
if (fetchedResultsController != nil && !newFetchRequired) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }
newFetchRequired = NO;
```

The fetch is then performed correctly (which calls and recreates the NSFRC):

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

I hope this helps anyone in a similar situation.

Thanks to Ashley for the alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to `performFetch:` ?

i.e.

```
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Yes, I'm performing the fetch, but the number of rows returned in numberOfRowsInSection is 0.

Comment: Can log fetchRequest just to confirm it contains what you're expecting (and post here?)

Comment: The fetch request shows that the search term is nil. <NSFetchRequest: 0x5a52dd0> (entity: Student; predicate: (university == nil); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(stuName, ascending, compare:)"
)); batch size: 20; type: NSManagedObjectResultType; ). The university is nil when the NSFRC is created. How can I get this to update to use the selected university?

Comment: Add a `selected` attribute to your University entity, which gets set when the university is selected in the first tableView, then change your predicate to `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"university.selected == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]];`

Comment: Thanks Ashley. Looks like that will work, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it as I'll either have to deselect the previously selected university then select the new one, or loop through all of them to deselect them first. Funny thing is, I just tried recreating the NSFRC every time it's called (so the predicate term is not nil) and adding a universityID to the University model for the NSFRC to search on (instead of the University object itself). It still brings back 0 rows. I think there might be something more epically wrong than at first thought..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still checking this and I'm not quite sure if I understood your question correctly.. but why do you create the NSFRC from scratch when you just want to change the predicate? Here's how I would do it:

When a new University is selected just add in the code right there:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"university == %@",self.selectedUniversity];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
[fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

and you're done. (Sorry if this is totally not what you were looking for).

**edit:** You could also simply write this into a private function and call it every time a university is selected.